# How to install the Tink cryptographic library on Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, tink

I've created an app on App Engine with Java Maven quickstart.
But including the [Tink library](https://github.com/google/tink) in the dependencies and importing it the way described in its readme does not work as the library does not exist on Google Cloud and the readme is not intended for it.

I'm quite familiar with Java but new to Maven and GCP.
How do I install the library manually?

UPD: The pre-built jar is available for [Tink 1.0.0](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.crypto.tink/tink/1.0.0)

Comment: In case of using the library for Google Payments API you can as well download the [Payment Method Token](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.crypto.tink/apps-paymentmethodtoken/1.0.0) implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about App Engine Flex, you can setup [dependencies](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/using-java-libraries); if you are talking about App Engine Standard, then you will need to manually download the jar files and place them in the library folders (/WEB-INF/lib).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I could not get it from the Google Cloud support. This must be the App Engine Standard plan, as it is a free trial.